# Correlation of vectors from different files

Tags: r

I have some vectors (around 50) stored in different (.R) files in the working directory.  The objects are all named with the same name. Suppose

```
A <- c(1,5,15, 25, 8, 20)
```

in one .R file,

in the  next file

```
A <- c(32,24,35,15, 16, 18)
```

and it is similar for other files.

Vectors have the same length.  Any ideas about doing this in R?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

```
 fileList <- list.files(pattern="\\.R")
 library(Hmisc)
 rcorr(sapply(fileList, function(x) source(x)$value))$r
```